# How to enable drag and drop on mobile using React (not native)

Tags: android, reactjs, mobile, frontend, drag-and-drop

```
  <div
        draggable={true}
        onDrag={() => {
          console.log("dragging");
        }}
        onDragOver={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
        }}
        onDrop={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(e);
          console.log("drop");
        }}
        style={{ color: "green", touchAction: "none" }}
      >
        drag me
      </div>
```

This is my current implementation. It works on desktop browser, but not on android touch screen.

How to make it work on mobile touch screen?